# php foreach key as a class variable

Tags: php, foreach

Can someone please tell me if this method of doing foreach has drawbacks?

```
class someclass {
  function foo() {
    foreach ($my_array as $this->key => $this->value) {
      $this->bar();
      $this->baz();
    }
  }
  function bar(){
    //do something with $this->key or $this->value
  }
  function baz(){
    //do something with $this->key or $this->value
  }
}
```

Comment: Ew. That is all.

Comment: the biggest draw back is readability as u can already see ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty inefficient as you are essentially setting the key to an associative array on each loop. I would keep them local and then assign them when the loop is done if you need to store them. Also, pass the values to the methods when you call them.

```
class SomeClass {
    function foo($myArray) {
       foreach ($myArray as $key => $value){
           $this->bar($key);
           $this->baz($value);
        }
        $this->key = $key;
        $this->value = $value;
     }
    function bar($key){
     //do something with $this->key or $this->value
    }
    function baz($value){
     //do something with $this->key or $this->value
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Matt.  I have always done the way you suggested.  Just thought of this a few minutes ago and was curious.

Comment: `It's pretty inefficient as you are essentially setting the key to an associative array on each loop.` Huh? How do you mean? `$this->key` is set to a scalar value (namely the key of the array item) on each iteration. Or am I misinterpreting what you are saying?

Comment: I am referring to the time it takes to resolve the property name to a memory address. This is because the class implementation is something like a hash table or associative array.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the keys and values to be accessible publicly in your methods, I'd go with:

```
class someclass{
    function foo($my_array){
       foreach ($my_array as $key => $value){
           $this->loopArray[$key] = $value;
           $this->bar();
           $this->baz();
        }

     }
    function bar(){
        //do something with $this->key or $this->value

    }
    function baz(){
        //do something with $this->key or $this->value
    }

 }

 $obj = new someclass();
 $my_array = array('value1','value2');
 $obj->foo($my_array);
 var_dump($obj->loopArray);
```

Outputs:

> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "value1" [1]=> string(6) "value2" }